# Prove that if $p$ is a prime, then $p$ is a factor of $\binom{p}{r}$ for $r=1,2,\dots,p-1$ by using induction.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that if $p$ is a prime, then $p$ is a factor of $\binom{p}{r}$ for $r=1,2,\dots,p-1$ by using induction.

First, $\binom{p}{1}=p$. So it is clear that it has factor $p$.
Suppose that $\binom{p}{k}$ has factor $p$ for some $k\geq1$.
Then $$\binom{p}{k+1}=\frac{p-k}{k+1}\binom{p}{k}$$
Here, I can't think of how to use the induction hypothesis since $\frac{p-k}{k+1}$ is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: You do not need induction. The denominator of $\binom{p}{r}$ clearly is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: Rewrite as $(k+1)\binom{p}{k+1}=(p-k)\binom{p}{k}$.

Comment: @Peter Ya I know that, but the question requires me to do by induction on $r$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your hint. Do you mean that since $p$ does not divide $k+1$, hence $p$ divide $\binom{p}{k+1}$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Hmm, I think you will need to make a special case for $k = p - 1$ wouldn't you?  An easy special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as $(k+1)\binom{p}{k+1}=(p-k)\binom{p}{k}$.

Note that $p$ divides the right-hand side, and does not divide $k+1$, so it must divide $\binom{p}{k+1}$.

Comment: By induction this will show for $1 \le k < p - 1$.  I think you need to make a special case for $k = p - 1$.  Then $(k+1)({p \choose {k+1}}) = (p-k){p \choose k} \iff p{ p \choose p} = {p \choose {p-1}} \iff p = {p \choose {p - 1}}$.

Comment: @fleablood: We are only going to $r=p-1$ so the last relevant $k$ is $p-2$.

Comment: Oh... right.  p-1 is a result of that induction.  D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

You are off to a good start, here is a **hint** for how to continue.

Multiply your equation by $k+1$ to give
$$(k+1)\binom{p}{k+1}=(p-k)\binom pk\ .$$
By assumption $p\mid RHS$, so $p\mid LHS$.  But $p\not\mid k+1$ because . . . and therefore 
$$p\mid\binom{p}{k+1}$$
because . . .

See if you can fill in the reasons indicated by dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a recursive definition of $\binom{p}{r}$ then this is easy to show via the definition of a prime.  The explicit formula is:

$$
\binom{p}{r} = \frac{p!}{(p-r)!r!} \\
\binom{p}{r+1} = \frac{p!}{(p-r-1)!(r+1)!} = \frac{p!}{(p-r)!r!}\frac{p - r}{r+1}
$$

$$
\binom{p}{r+1} = \binom{p}{r}\frac{p-r}{r+1}
$$

So start with your base case:

$$
\binom{p}{1} = p
$$

This clearly is divisible by $p$.  Now use the inductive step.  If $p$ is prime *and* $\binom{p}{r}$ is divisible by $p$, then $\binom{p}{r+1}$ must also be divisible by $p$:

This is because we have $\binom{p}{r+1} = \binom{p}{r}\frac{p - r}{r+1}$--therefore the only way that $\binom{p}{r+1}$ is *not* divisible by $p$ is if $r+1$ is can "break down" $p$. I.e. that $r + 1$ shares a factor of $p$--which is not possible by the definition of prime $p$ (along with the fact that we are saying $r + 1 < p$).

I want to make this concrete, let's say we have $p = 12$ (not prime). Eventually this number will be broken down (will be divided): when $r + 1 = 2$ and (possibly) again when $r + 1= 3, 4, 6$. I don't know whether or not $2^{12} - 2$ is divisible by $12$ or not--all I can say is that I'm "not sure".

On the other hand if I choose $p = 11$ (a prime). I know that *none* of the numbers below $11$ can divide it and thus every "middle" number in Pascal's triangle must be divisible by $11$...therefore $2^{11} - 2$ is divisible by $11$ and likewise $2^{11} - 2 = 2(2^{10} - 1)$ must also be--therefore $n$ divides $2^{n - 1} - 1$ if $n$ is prime (which is a very small part of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)).